# Handling cryptic output when printing bytes array in C

Tags: c, gcc, output

I've recently encountered a problem with a script I wrote.

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2){

    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    char * word = (char *) malloc(strlen(word1)+ strlen(word2) );
    strcpy(word,word1);
    strcat(word,word2);
    MD5_Update(&md5,word,strlen(word));
    unsigned char* digest = malloc(sizeof(char)* 16); //MD5 generates 128bit hashes, each char has 4 bit, 128/4 = 32
    MD5_Final(digest,&md5);
    return digest;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* a = argv[1];
    char* b = argv[2];

    unsigned char* ret = hashfunc(a,b);
    printf("%s\n",ret);
    printf("%i\n",sizeof(ret));
}
```

As the hash function returns an array of unsigned chars I thought I'd print that as is.
Unfortunately, the following is my output:
��.�@a��%Ćw�0��
which, according to `sizeof()` is 8 bytes long.
How do I convert that to a readable format?

Thanks in advance!

PS:
Output should look like this:

```
1c0143c6ac7505c8866d10270a480dec
```

Comment: In each malloc, you fail to allocate memory for the terminating null. Also, sizeof ret gives the size of the pointer, not the length of the string. Finally, you have a memory leak because you do not free word.

Comment: When I assign a +1 in malloc for the terminating null, that doesn't change a thing. Can you point me in the right direction on whats wrong? Do I have to append the terminating null manually?

Comment: You're getting the MD5 bytes. You want to convert it to a hexadecimal representation of those bytes. Probably the easiest way is to use the `printf` `%x` format specifier with each byte.

Comment: you don't need the first `malloc`/`strcpy`/`strcat`, just call `MD5_Update` twice

Comment: @M.M This does yield a different result though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `sizeof` a pointer will give the size of a pointer to `char`, which is the size of a word in your machine (I suppose it’s 64-bit, since your size returned 8). Pointers do not carry information of the size of the pointer, you’d have to return it elsewhere.

Anyway, since you know that a MD5 digest has 16 bytes, you can just iterate over each of them and print each byte in a more readable format using sprintf. Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02x", (int)(unsigned char)digest[i]);
putchar('\n');
```

If you want to print it to a file, change `printf` to `fprintf` and `putchar` to `fputc` (the arguments change a bit however).

To put it into a string, you’d have to `sprint` each byte in the correct position of the string, something like this:

```
char* str = malloc(33 * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    sprintf(str+2*i, "%02x", (int)(unsigned char)digest[i]);
```

P.S: don’t forget to `free` everything after.

Comment: `ret` is pointer to plain char , so either the chars need to be cast to `unsigned char` first, or use `unsigned char *` for `ret`

Comment: I changed it to unsigned char* for ret. However, how would I go about storing this readable output in a string / char array?

Comment: @DanielSiegel Edited my answer to add print to string

Comment: For some reason the string I construct using your method gets leading zeroes at it's end. Something of the form: 980642b56fbdabbd5456cdd7d8005ec500000000000000000000000000000000

Can you explain why? @JoaoBapt

Comment: @DanielSiegel I got the error, it’s on your code too. A 128-bit hash has actually 16 bytes, not 32. Going to update the answer, and you update your code.

Comment: @JoaoBapt yup that was the error. Thank you very much for your help.   I updated the code.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that your `hashfunc` is going to produce printable ASCII strings. In theory since they are really just binary data they could have embedded 0s which will screw up all the normal string handling functions anyway.

Best bet is to print each unsigned char as an unsigned char via a for loop.

```
void printhash(unsigned char* hash)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```